# Use a generator to create a list of dictionaries with a set of labels

Tags: python, dictionary, generator

Say I have a function `get_call_value(row, column)` that returns the value of a spreadsheet cell. I have a set of labels that correspond to the columns. I want to build a list of dictionaries, the keys of which are the column labels. Here's what I have so far:

```
def _get_rows(self, start_key=1):
    # List holding lists representing rows
    out_data = []

    # Get row count
    row_count = num_rows()
    column_count = num_columns()

    def get_label_value(row, column):
      """Generator for getting the cell value at row, column of an Excel sheet
      """
      labels = {
        0: 'label_1',
        1: 'label_2',
        2: 'label_3',
      }
      yield (labels[column], get_cell_value(row, column))

   return {key: value for (key, value) in get_label_value(xrange(start_key, row_count), xrange(column_count))}
```

My stack trace ends in an error along the lines of:

```
get_label_value
    yield (labels[column], get_cell_value(row, column))
KeyError: xrange(31)
```

I'm obviously not understanding how the generator is supposed to work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Edit:
I think further clarification is needed and I see an error in my logic concerning what I want to do. My expected result is a list of dictionaries. The keys in the dictionaries are the column labels and the values are the cell values at the (row, column), like so:

```
[
  {'label_1': value_1,
   'label_2': value_2,
   'label_3': value_3,
  },
  {
   'label_1': another_value_1,
...
  }
]
```

With that in mind, the return statement in my should be this then?

return [{key: value for (key, value) in get_label_value(xrange(start_key, row_count), xrange(column_count))}]

Comment: What is the expected result? what do expect xrange to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass an entire `xrange` object to the `labels` dict right now, which is why you're seeing that exception. What you actually want to do is iterate over the two `xrange` objects you're passing to `get_label_value`, so that you can build your desired list of dicts:

```
def _get_rows(self, start_key=1):
    # List holding lists representing rows
    out_data = []

    # Get row count
    row_count = num_rows()
    column_count = num_columns()

    def get_label_value(rows, columns):
      """Generator for getting the cell value at row, column of an Excel sheet
      """
      labels = {
        0: 'label_1',
        1: 'label_2',
        2: 'label_3',
      }
      # Yield a dict for each row in the table. The dict contains all the
      # cells for a given row in the table, where the keys are column labels,
      # each mapped to a given cell in the row.
      for row in rows:
          yield {labels[column] : get_cell_value(row, column) for column in columns}

    return [cell_dict for cell_dict in get_label_value(xrange(start_key, row_count), xrange(column_count))]
```

Comment: dano, I edited my question; I don't think I was clear in my desired result.

Comment: This worked except the comma in the yield line should be a colon. SO won't let me edit it if it's not over six characters for some reason.

Comment: @ericso Thanks, I fixed that. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Another question: what if I wanted to add a key-value pair to the dictionary being yielded? I want to tack on {'row_number': row}. The closest thing I could think of is using update() in the yield statement but update() returns None. Ideas?

Comment: @ericso Just don't yield directly from the dict comprehension, and split it into three lines: `d = {labels[column] : ...} ; d['row_number'] = row ; yield d`